# Show complex number in polar coordinates and in polar form

Tags: complex-numbers

I'm a but stuck with this problem

> Represent in polar form and graph in the complex plane as in Fig. 325. Do these problems very carefully

$$\frac{\sqrt{2} + \frac{i}{3}}{-\sqrt{8} - \frac{2i}{3}}$$
$$= \frac{\sqrt{2} + \frac{i}{3}}{(2*-\sqrt{2}) - \frac{2i}{3}}$$
$$= \frac{\sqrt{2} + \frac{i}{3}}{-2(\sqrt{2} + \frac{i}{3})}$$
$$= \frac{-1}{2}$$

Where do I go from here?

Comment: But I don't understand the question!, could you make it more clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $$-\frac{1}{2}=-\frac{1}{2}+i\cdot0=\frac{1}{2}e^{i(\pi+2n\pi)}$$ for $n\in\mathbb Z$, so take $n=0$ and we get $-\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{2}e^{i\pi}$

[image]